# How do you Convert a TIF file to a PDF file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert TIF files into PDF Files.  Below is the code that does the conversion however, when it converts i loose the content in the TIF files and only get blank PDF files.  How do I convert the files and keep the picture on the original TIF file.

```
$InputLocation = "C:\convert"





$tool = 'C:Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe'
$tiffs = get-childitem  -filter *.tif -path $InputLocation

foreach($tiff in $tiffs)
{
    $filename = $tiff.FullName
    $pdf = $tiff.FullName.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'


    'Processing ' + $filename  + ' to ' + $pdf      
    $param = "-sOutputFile=$pdf"
    & $tool /IF$filename /OF$pdf /NoPSCheck /NoStart

}
```

Comment: do you need to create ps file first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Preet Sangha has said, you need to double quote the parameters.

This should do it:

```
$InputLocation = "C:\convert"

$tool = 'C:Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe'
$tiffs = get-childitem  -filter *.tif -path $InputLocation

foreach($tiff in $tiffs)
{
    $filename = $tiff.FullName
    $pdf = $tiff.FullName.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'


    'Processing ' + $filename  + ' to ' + $pdf      
    $param = "-sOutputFile=$pdf"
    Start-Process $tool -ArgumentList ('/IF"' + $filename + '" /OF"' + $pdf + '/NoPSCheck /NoStart')
}
```

**EDIT:** Changed to use Start-Process instead of &

Comment: The term 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe/IF"C:\convert\00020001.TIF" /OF"C:\convert\00020001.pdf"/NoPSChec
k /NoStart' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
 name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At M:\Powershell\convert.ps1:18 char:6
+  & <<<<  ($tool + '/IF"' + $filename + '" /OF"' + $pdf +  '"/NoPSCheck /NoStart')+CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound:(C:\Program File...SCheck /NoStart:String)[],CommandNotFoundException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId:CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @user2471571 - My mistake, hadn't had the time to try the code, just amended your existing code.

Have amended to use Start-Process instead to run the program. I don't have the PDF Creator software to fully test but give it a go.

Comment: I really appreciate all the help.  It is running with no errors now but it is "deleting" the file now.  I am guessing it could be something to do with the output path

Comment: Is it deleting the source or the destination?

Comment: According to the vendor support site the IF/OF commands are only for converting from .ps (postscript) files. For everything else, they advise you to use the PF (print file) command. The poster had what sounds like the same issue as you, input file deleted even though DeleteIF option was not set.   http://forums.pdfforge.org/discussion/10806/when-using-pdfcreator-command-line-it-generates-an-empty-pdf-document/p1

Comment: @GrahamGold: when I try this I get the PDFCreator 2.3 window popping up, with two buttons: one for "Application Settings" and the other for "Profile Settings". No TIF gets converted to a PDF. Any ideas?

Comment: @val I don't have PDF Creator, but a quick google suggests they've removed all but one of the command line options in the latest releases of their product - http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/manual/command-line-parameters

Comment: @GrahamGold i found this line to work using imagemagick:     convert $filename -density 300x300 -compress jpeg $pdf. see this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719125/imagemagick-or-ghostscript-convert-a-multi-page-tiff-to-a-multi-page-pdf

Comment: @val thanks - if the OP ever pops back in here, because PDF Creator doesn't support command line anymore, an alternative is here for them :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [command line reference](http://www.pdfforge.org/content/command-line-parameters) you need double quotes around the file names and the output format.

e.g.

```
pdfcreator.exe /IF"C:\description.ps" /OF"C:\description.pdf" /OutputSubFormat"PDF/A-1b"
```